# How to lock a package to not be updated or reinstalled in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I've already installed a patched version of a package, and I don't want it be updated or reinstalled in any case.

What I have tried but not success:

- using `exclude=package-name*` in `/etc/yum.conf`: I can still yum reinstall package-name.rpm
- using `yum versionlock package-name`: same as above, I can still yum reinstall package-name.rpm

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `yum versionlock` or `yum-versionlock` which one did you use? This question is for [Unix and Linux stack exchange.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

> using `yum versionlock package-name`: same as above, I can still yum reinstall package-name.rpm

You should use [`yum-versionlock`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yum-versionlock.1.html) instead because that is the `yum` plug-in that does the job.

> **SYNOPSIS** 
> yum-versionlock [ package-name [ package-name]] ...
>
> **DESCRIPTION** 
> yum-versionlock is a Yum plugin that takes a set of
> name/versions for packages and excludes all other versions of
> those packages (including optionally following obsoletes).  **This
> allows you to protect packages from being updated by newer
> versions.** 
>  [The Man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yum-versionlock.1.html#top_of_page)

Comment: it is the same, I installed yum-plugin-versionlock

Comment: IMO you should not have messed with your yum.conf file though